# CORS error :Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http-headers, cors

I am trying to send the request from one localhost port to the another. I am using **angularjs on the frontend and node on the backend**.

Since it is **CORS** request, In node.js, i am using

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
```

and in the angular.js service file, I am using

```
return {
    getValues: $resource(endpoint + '/admin/getvalues', null, {
        'get': {
             method: 'GET',
             headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer'+' '+ $localStorage.token}
             }
     }),
}
```

I am getting the following error

**Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Please help!

Comment: you need to put auth in server to, and in firefox doesnt need this auth

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón, i put this res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'); in server

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to add options also in allowed headers. browser sends a preflight request before original request is sent. See below

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
```

From source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

> In CORS, a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters. The `Access-Control-Request-Method` header notifies the server as part of a preflight request that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a POST request method. The `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header notifies the server that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a `X-PINGOTHER` and `Content-Type` custom headers.  The server now has an opportunity to determine whether it wishes to accept a request under these circumstances.

**EDITED**

You can avoid this manual configuration by using [npmjs.com/package/cors](http://npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package.I have used this method also, it is clear and easy.

Comment: Changed res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH'); to res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');                                                                    still not working

Comment: res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');//have to expose so that browser have permissions to access this header

Comment: solution i have given worked for me. did it worked for you? if not you can also try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors . I have used this method also it is clear and easy.

Comment: The previous solution didn't work, let me try this one.

Comment: Tried npmjs.com/package/cors . library and its working

Comment: Please include it in your answer so that I can upvote it

Comment: It solved the problem after debugging for more than 3 hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

This is an API issue, you won't get this error if using Postman/Fielder to send HTTP requests to API. In case of browsers, for security purpose, they always send OPTIONS request/preflight to API before sending the actual requests (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE). Therefore, in case, the request method is OPTION, not only you need to add "Authorization" into "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", but you need to add "OPTIONS" into "Access-Control-allow-methods" as well. This was how I fixed:

```
if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { (string)context.Request.Headers["Origin"] });
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" });
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });

        }
```

Answer (score 9):

The `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` wouldn't work with Autorization header.
Just enable pre-flight request, using [cors library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors())
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to install the cors library and instead want to fix your original code, the other step you are missing is that Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* is wrong. When passing Authentication tokens (e.g. JWT) then you must explicitly state every url that is calling your server. You can't use "*" when doing authentication tokens.

Comment: *"When passing Authentication tokens (e.g. JWT) then you must explicitly state every url that is calling your server. You can't use "*" when doing authentication tokens."* - This is wrong. On what basis are you saying this?

Answer (score 4):

First you **need to install** `cors` by using below command :

```
npm install cors --save
```

Now **add the following code** to your app starting file like ( `app.js or server.js`)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//enables cors
app.use(cors({
  'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
  'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
  'origin': '*',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'preflightContinue': false
}));

require('./router/index')(app);
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone getting this using ServiceStack backend; add "Authorization" to allowed headers in the [Cors plugin](https://docs.servicestack.net/corsfeature):

`Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(allowedHeaders: "Content-Type,Authorization"));`

Answer (score -4):

1. add this chrome extension
   [cors unblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en)
   and enable "Enable Access-Control-[Allow/Expose]-Headers".
2. Also open Test cors in the same menu and test all the available options. Click on each of the options and make sure you get the success message(in green) for each option.
3. reload your application. Cors errors is gone now.

Comment: would you do this to all clients pcs?

Comment: No this is just a temporary fix.

Comment: Ahaa okay, it's better to put a note on your answers then.. Some dev might think this shall solve to all clients out there