# Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers Error

Tags: express, vue.js, cors

I have a VueJS application and a ExpressJS server side application. On my server I have the following:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I'm sending my request like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.com',
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  }
})
```

How can I get around this? I have tried many solutions and read up on this. I have read the below:

- [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)
- [CORS error :Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061727/cors-error-request-header-field-authorization-is-not-allowed-by-access-control)
- [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by itself in preflight response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr)

Comment: Is your server responding to the OPTIONS request which is what the browser will send to preflight your request to see if it's allowed?  I'd suggest you look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see exactly what the browser is sending and what your server is responding with.  Usually, you can see the problem more precisely in that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question apparently isn’t causing the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header to get sent for `OPTIONS` responses — specifically, for the response to [the CORS preflight `OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

To ensure preflight `OPTIONS` get handled correctly, consider installing the npm `cors` package:

```
npm install cors
```

And then do something like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();
app.options('*', cors()); // preflight OPTIONS; put before other routes
```

That will handle CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests and other CORS aspects without you needing to manually write your own handling from scratch in your application code.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-option has more details on all the  options.

Comment: Worked here! Thank you!